# Posting JSON to Restlet using xstream and jettison results in "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I am using the jse edition of Restlet 2.1.0 with the xstream and jettison extensions that enable me to have a resource that is declared like this:

```
@Get("json")
public Customer retrieve();
```

This allows me to have a client that can choose whether to get a JSON string or get a Customer object, with xstream+jettison doing the serialization/deserialization.

I also have a resource method declared like this:

```
@Post
public Customer store(Customer customer);
```

Which I can post to using something like:

```
clientResource.post(customer, Customer.class);
```

This all seems to work nicely.  However the one thing that doesn't work is the simplest scenario, of posting a JSON String to this Post Restlet resource.

When I try to post the following JSON String:

```
{"com.redprairie.task.common.Customer":{"firstName":"George","lastName":"Shaw","birthDate":"1856-07-26 07:00:00.0 UTC","address":"Bibbs Hall Lane, Ayot St. Lawrence, AL6 9BX  United Kingdom"}}
```

I get this stack trace:

```
<failure message="Unsupported Media Type (415) - Unsupported Media Type" type="org.restlet.resource.ResourceException">Unsupported Media Type (415) - Unsupported Media Type
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1203)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1070)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1087)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1438)
    at com.redprairie.task.common.rest.RestletResource.post(RestletResource.java:99)
    at com.redprairie.task.common.rest.ServerResourceTest.testPostMethodUsingJSON(ServerResourceTest.java:165)
```

I'm guessing there is something simple that I'm doing wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue.

I was trying to post a JSON string using:

```
String jsonString = "{some valid json}";
clientResource.post(jsonString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

That didn't work.  Not sure exactly why it didn't work, but doing it the following way works:

```
Representation rep = new StringRepresentation(jsonString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
clientResource.post(rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the [content-type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) in your POST request header?

Comment: I tried it it using resource.post(jsonString), resource.post(jsonString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) and I get the same error in both cases.